# Strange behaviour of Scanner class

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Why does Scanner behave in such a strange way?

When ever I take input for an integer followed by string ,it never takes it?

like for example

```
Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
int i=s.nextInt();
String str=s.nextLine();
String str2=s.nextLine();
```

We can never input a value for a string str,it straightways go to str2?why so?

Comment: How are you separating the fields? Newline? The newline isn't part of the integer. So you then get an "empty line".

Comment: Have you tried using s.next() instead of nextLine()?

Comment: Have you read the documentation of `Scanner#nextLine`?

Comment: nextInt()  reads an integer, but it stays on the current line. The first nextLine() method returns the rest of the current line (excluding the line separator) and advances to the next line. The second nextLine() retrieves your String.